# Example of f integrable and g not integrable, with fg integrable

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm looking for an example of two functions \begin{equation} f,g:\textbf{R}\subset\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R \end{equation} where ***f*** it's Riemann integrable in **R** and ***g*** it's not, but ***fg*** is integrable. But the only example I have of a non integrable function is the Dirichlet Function.

Comment: What about $f(x)=0$?

Comment: Well we need to think in reverse. If $f, g$ are Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ and $g$ is bounded away from zero in $[a, b]$ then $f/g$ is integrable. This means that we need to choose some integrable function $h$ and some integrable $f$, but at the same time $f$ should not be bounded away from zero and let $g = h/f$. Thus we choose $h(x) = 1$, $f(x) = x, g(x) = 1/x $ and $g(0) = 1, f(0) = 1$ on interval $[0, 1]$.

Comment: An issue I find with the question is the use of "Riemann integrable in $\mathbb{R}$". Riemann integration is defined only for closed intervals and extension to unbounded intervals is done by a further limit process which is called improper Riemann integration.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: There is a unique function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $f\cdot g=f$ for all $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

You can take $f$ to be the Dirichlet function on $[0,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere,  and $g$ to be $0$ on $[0,1 ]$ and $1$ elsewhere.

Comment: The question asks for an integrable $f$.

Comment: You are right. Thanks.